# How to kill a command process inside Kubernetes pod without crashing pod

Tags: java, kubernetes

I have a K8s Deployment that runs a Linux Docker image with Java and executes a sh script command running a Java process that on pod startup and it fails shortly after starting, triggering a pod crash and re-creation. It's a Java issue and logs are not helpful so I want to stop it before it fails and explore the pod file system and environemnt.

If I just try to `kill` the java PID the pod crashes instantly. Is there any way I can stop the Java process (without altering the program or sh script code) from inside the pod shell before it gets to the part of crashing, and not trigger a pod crash?

Thanks!

Comment: You can always pull the image and start it locally with an interactive shell, starting the java application from within the interactive shell.

Comment: The setup is a bit complex with Jenkins/Helm/EKS and it injects various env vars dynamically and pulls some files at startup from external sources using secrets from K8s so I was hoping there is a way to do this on runtime.

Comment: You could try to start a second container within the pod with a "busy waiting"-loop to keep the pod running. I know that this is possible, but not exactly how it is done.

Answer (score 2):

Starting from Kubernetes 1.19 you can debug running pods using [Ephemeral Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/debug-application-cluster/debug-running-pod/#ephemeral-container) and `kubectl debug` command.